# putting concrete footer with slab

Tags: concrete

I am going to install a pavilion on a concrete slab.  I was wondering, if I install 4 ft concrete footers, should the top of the column be flush with the top of the slab to be poured, or the column be just to the top of the bottom of the slab to be poured, where the rest of the concrete covering the footer would be from the slab.  Any info would be great.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You mention a column as the footer, so I'm assuming this is a post framed type of structure with the posts sitting on concrete piers.  If so, the posts must be supported directly on the piers, not on a slab poured over the pier.  You can do this by either extending the pier to the top of the slab and using a support like this (Simpson EPB44T) with the slab poured around the pier:

[image]

Or you can bring your pier to the bottom of the slab and use this style of support (Simpson PPBZ Porch Base), which you anchor to the pier, and then pour the slab over/around it:

[image]

This is NOT engineering advice - I suggest you talk to one to properly spec out this component for your application!

(just realized this question is 5 months old and probably OBE, not sure how it ended up on my feed - hopefully you got it right)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you pour everything at once. If you pour the footers first, then you should make them below and pour the slab on top.

Comment: Right. (Not sure why the downvote.) There's no reason that you can't pour this as a "thickened edge" footing/slab monolith. To avoid cracks along the inner edges of the footings, taper the inner edge of the footing up to the slab at a 45-degree angle.